# How to update NetSuite "sales order status" using Mule NetSuite Connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, netsuite

I am very new to Mule NetSuite Connector. I am trying to update NetSuite Sales Order status using NetSuite Connector.

I have written configuration xml like below to update the sales order.

```
<flow name="netsuite-create-sales-orderFlow2" doc:name="netsuite-create-sales-orderFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8084" path="UpdateSalesOrder" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <netsuite:update-record config-ref="Netsuite" recordType="SALES_ORDER" doc:name="Netsuite">
        <netsuite:attributes>
            <tranId>299</tranId>
            <orderStatus>_pendingFulfillment</orderStatus>
        </netsuite:attributes>
    </netsuite:update-record>
</flow>
```

In the above code '299' is my sales order number and I am trying update that sales order status from "_pendingApproval" to "_pendingFulfillment". But I am getting 'IllegalArgumentException".

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.netsuite.webservices.transactions.sales_2013_2.types.SalesOrderOrderStatus._pendingFulfillment
```

Can some one please correct me Where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with

```
 <netsuite:attribute key="orderStatus" value="PENDING_FULFILLMENT"/>
```

Comment: `<netsuite:attributes>
           <tranId>299</tranId>
           <netsuite:attribute key="orderStatus" value="PENDING_FULFILLMENT"/> 
</netsuite:attributes>`
I have changed the code as above but didn't work for me. I am getting the same IllegaleArgumentException.

Comment: Try to retrieve the Internal ID for PENDING_FULFILLMENT and put that as a value. It should be a 2 digits number (standard list if I remember correctly)

Comment: after adding 'internalId' its working fine. I have configured like this
`<netsuite:update-record config-ref="Netsuite" recordType="SALES_ORDER" doc:name="Netsuite">
         <netsuite:attributes>
                <netsuite:attribute key="orderStatus">PENDING_FULFILLMENT</netsuite:attribute>
                <netsuite:attribute key="internalId">14392</netsuite:attribute>
      </netsuite:attributes>
        </netsuite:update-record>`

Answer (score 1):

Use : **PENDING_FULFILLMENT** Or **#[com.netsuite.webservices.transactions.sales_2013_2.types.SalesOrderOrderStatus.SalesOrderOrderStatus.PENDING_FULFILLMENT]**  (You can use global imports to hide that verbose pacakge - http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips)

You can refer to the possible enum values here (Under "Summary"):http://mulesoft.github.io/netsuite-connector/java/com/netsuite/webservices/transactions/sales_2013_2/types/SalesOrderOrderStatus.html

Comment: I have tried with "PENDING_FULFILLMENT" but I am getting below Exception
`org.mule.module.netsuite.api.NetSuiteGenericException: ERROR_CODE:INVALID_KEY_OR_REF MESSAGE:The specified key is invalid. STATUS_TYPE: ERROR`